# try catch not working with Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I have this Powershell code:

```
Function blah
{
...
try
{
    $numct = ( Get-ChildItem "\\devicename\c$\Users\user\Documents\ShareFile\Folders" -ea "Stop" | Measure-Object ).Count;
}
catch
{
    "Error: " + $($_.Exception.Message)
    return $false
}
```

It works in a successful scenario, but if you say change `devicename` to a fake device it does not fall into the `catch` section.

Comment: Is it showing error text but not going into the `catch` block? If so what is the error text? The error might be happening in `Measure-Object`, though that seems unlikely. Adding `-ErrorAction Stop` to that too would rule it out quickly.

Comment: @briantist I'm not getting any error msg in the output window. If I take out `-ea "Stop"` I at least get error in the output window, but still not falling into the catch

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I run your snippet, the catch block is entered, the following is returned:
Error: Cannot find path '\\devicename\c$\Users\user\Documents\ShareFile\Folders' because it does not exist.
False

Comment: Oh I think I see the problem here. This code snippet is taken out of context I think? Was it originally in a function? If so the `"Error: " + $($_.Exception.Message)` line is *returning* that message as the return value of the function, but it may not display it. It looks more like it's intended to be displayed, which warrants a call to `Write-Host`, `Write-Verbose`, `Write-Error`, etc. Just a stab in the dark..

Comment: @briantist Yes it's in a function. Good catch, that solved it

Comment: I'll post my comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet looks like it was originally in a function?

If so the `"Error: " + $($_.Exception.Message)` line is returning that message as the return value of the function, but it may not display it.

Since it's intended to be displayed it warrants a call to `Write-Host`, `Write-Verbose`, `Write-Error`, etc.

By just using the value alone, you are implicitly calling `Write-Object`, which in a function returns the object to its caller.

Once you are out all functions, the host decides what to do with it (typically display it). Use one of the above functions to explicitly write text.